# Is this bad practice? Redirect pointer pointing to blank string to another string?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Consider this snippet,

```
char *p1="";
printf("p1=%p\np1=%s\n",p1,p1);

char s1[6]="abcde";
printf("s1=%p\ns1=%s\n",s1,s1);

p1=s1;

printf("p1=%p\np1=%s\n",p1,p1);
```

Since, none of the variables are allocated on heap, all allocated space will be freed at the end of process.

**Questions:**

- What happens to the blank string when the pointer pointing to it is redirected to another string? (As per my basic Java knowledge, incase of Java the blank string will be eligible for GC to be collected. What happens here?)
- In case the code was longer, will the blank string utilise memory unecessarily till the end?
- Valgrind does not report memory leaks (i guess this refers to heap memory only? ). Is there a scenario where such coding practise cause a bottleneck?

Comment: if you want the empty string literal to be located on the stack you have to declare `p1` as `char p1[] = "";` otherwise p1 is only a pointer that lies on the stack but pointing to data in the data segment.

Comment: All allocated space for your program will be freed when your process terminates, regardless if it is global data, runtime stack/heap, or text segment. Memory leaks are a problem while your program runs - they do not persist past the lifetime of the process (or at least the executable image for an exec call).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your strings `""` and `"abcde"` live in the (read-only) data section of your executable. They are loaded into memory when your program is loaded.

When no more pointers point to it, then no more pointers point to it. That's all.

Programs have lots of read-only data (for example, the entire program's code!) It's not really something to be concerned with.

This is not considered a memory leak, just as having a function that never gets called is not a memory leak. After the program is loaded, nothing is ever allocated or de-allocated.

Comment: Thanks Reinhart. I have another question -> Which mechanism is used to handle the read only strings i.e. remove the unused ones and stuff?

Comment: @VusP It's up to your compiler and/or linker to remove *anything* unused, including program code. This may require optimizations to be enabled.

Comment: s1 is not part of the global memory section. It is allocated as a local variable on the stack. It is also an array, not a pointer. It is of course still not a memory leak as it will be "de-allocated" when the function returns and a later function call will have its stack frame overwriting it.

Answer (score 2):

`""` is not a variable, it is a ***string literal***. No matter what you do with your variables, string literals remain in your program throughout the whole execution.

They are constant data stored in the `.rodata` section (read-only data) of your program. On a desktop program, `.rodata` is a reserved part of RAM. On an embedded system with real flash, `.rodata` is true read-only memory.

Compilers use clever optimizing tricks to store string literals in a so-called "string pool". Meaning that if you use several literals with the same contents, they will only be allocated once.

So there are no memory leaks here. However, it is good practice to declare all pointers to string literals as `const char*`, because you are not allowed to modify a string literal.

Comment: Thanks Lundin. So that means the `""` would continue to use space in `.rodata` until the program completes. So I assume, it should be possibly preferred not to allocate a `""` (which doesn't help in the logic of the code) to a pointer and then overwrite it with another string literal. This is just unneccesarily clogging up the `.rodata`

Comment: @VusP If you write code like  `const char* ptr = ""; ptr = "blabla";` it is unlikely that `""` will even get allocated in the first place. The compiler will remove it from the executable. If you intend to use ptr as a string, it is good practice to initialize it as you have, by pointing at an empty string literal.

Answer (score 0):

`p1` occupies enough bytes for a pointer;
`""` occupies 1 byte for the `'\0'`;
`s1` occupies 6 bytes;
`"abcde"` occupies 6 bytes.

All these bytes are at different locations. You need not worry about their management.

It is not bad practice to change what a pointer points to. Your snippet is ok (though you really should cast the addresses printed with `"%p"` to `void*`).